# Selecting such or such Prolog system in Emacs via prolog.el

Tags: emacs, prolog

Thierry Martinez changed prolog.el [(a package that provides a major mode for editing Prolog code in emac)](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/prolog.el) and provided [a couple of files](http://contraintes.inria.fr/%7Etmartine/prolog-mode/) by which it is possible to get a menu of Prolog systems in a mini-buffer. It was suggested to me (see below) that, via [directory local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html) and [prolog.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/prolog.el), it would be possible to associate the choice of such or such Prolog system to a given directory.  Unfortunately, I did not succeed to write a .dir-locals.el that works to select SWI Prolog in a directory, and another one to select for example Jekejeke Prolog or GNU Prolog. Therefore I went back to the solution given by Martinez. But I would be glad to understand in this case how [directory local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html) can work with [prolog.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/prolog.el). Help is welcome.

Comment: A suggestion: (optionally) instead of the filename, use the enclosing directory name to select between systems

Comment: In complement to this good suggestion, I just saw this web page: https://endlessparentheses.com/a-quick-guide-to-directory-local-variables.html

Comment: You might also consider asking here: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Is your question not anymore Thierry Martinez?
For Thierry Martinez I guess you only need to change this:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(
                                ("\\.pro$" . prolog-mode)
                                ("\\.pl$" . prolog-or-perl-mode)
                                ("\\.chr$" . chr-mode)
                                )
         auto-mode-alist))
```

Here is an example, but I am assuming that my Prolog
system is identified by "jekejeke" and not by "jekeprolog":

```
(defun prolog-mode-jekejeke ()
     "Specific prolog mode which uses Jekejeke Prolog"
     (interactive)
     (prolog-mode 'jekejeke))

(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(
                                ("\\.p$" . prolog-mode-jekejeke)
                                ("\\.pro$" . prolog-mode)
                                ("\\.pl$" . prolog-or-perl-mode)
                                ("\\.chr$" . chr-mode)
                                )
         auto-mode-alist))
```

I am refering to this file originally from Thierry Martinez:

```
;; prolog-mode loader
;; Thierry.Martinez@inria.fr
;; under GPLv3
```

[https://gist.github.com/jburse/2d5fd1d3dd8436acceca52fdfc537581#file-prolog-el](https://%5Cgist.github.com/jburse/2d5fd1d3dd8436acceca52fdfc537581#file-prolog-el)

Warning, I didn't test!

Comment: Thanks. You understood me correctly: my question is no longer about Martinez setup that indeed works well. It is now a question to learn directory local variables in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your prolog systems per-file, you can just include the following line at the beginning of your file.

```
%% -*- prolog-system: swi -*-
```

Replace swi with any system supported

```
eclipse - Eclipse Prolog
mercury - Mercury
sicstus - SICStus Prolog
swi     - SWI Prolog
gnu     - GNU Prolog
```

Now there are a few problems when working with multiple prolog systems:

1. After switching to a different system, the `mode-name` will not change. So if it was `Prolog[GNU]` previously even if the current buffer local value of `prolog-system` is `swi` the `mode-name` will **not** change to `Prolog[SWI]`.
2. <del>Whatever the buffer local value of `prolog-system` is, when you do `run-prolog` or type `C-c C-l` the prolog process started seems to be that of the global `prolog-system` value.
   This is a bug(which will hopefully be resolved)</del> [fixed](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/9ffbe99b119d032c4d62e422abf7cf6d78ecfdf52) now.
3. Current `prolog.el` does not have support of different interpreters running simultaneously. To run `gprolog` you have to halt `swipl` and vice-versa. All of them are fighting to control `*prolog*` buffer.

If you still want your original file suffix type of switching you can do something like this:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode gnuprolog-mode prolog-mode "GNU-Prolog"
  "This is just `prolog-mode'."
  (setq-local prolog-system 'gnu)
  (prolog-mode-variables))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("gnu\\.pl" . gnuprolog-mode))
```

Here any file with `gnu.pl` suffix will be opened in our `gnuprolog-mode` which is just a `prolog-mode` started with your choice of prolog-system.

<del>**WARNINGS**:</del> both fixed in **emacs-28**

1. With this code, syntax highlighting might not *(depends on how current your emacs is)* work properly due to a bug in `prolog.el` (it is [fixed](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/918a5eae179f7998e4872cc5cf2f301a21c36587) recently).
2. The interpreter started might not be the correct one due a still existing bug(it is [fixed](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/9ffbe99b119d032c4d62e422abf7cf6d78ecfdf52) now).

Comment: Thanks. I understand therefore that the most convenient option to use prolog.el with different Prolog system is probably Martinez's. Am I right?

Comment: For now, Emacs own `prolog-mode` will not support your use case. So That is likely your only option(it looks like an old variant of emacs `prolog-mode`, so I dont know how well it works). I use `%-*- prolog-system: swi -*-` and change between swi, gnu and switch between gnu-prolog and swi-prolog in the same `*prolog*` buffer to see if my query works the same with both of them.